# Is the sentence correct?

Tags: expressions

In China, the incidence of extrahepatic cholangiocarcinoma is increasing by 5 percents every year, which is the fastest rising cancer in digestive tract.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. **Proofreading questions ("Is this correct?", "Are there any mistakes?")** is off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance and edit your question with your own research/reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a research paper, the sentence lacks clear time frame and the clause which seems a statement of the result of what is described in the preview sentence.

In China, the incidence of extrahepatic cholangiocarcinoma has been increasing by 5 percentage in the past 5 years. That marks it as the fastest rising cancer in the digestive system.

"Is increasing" is present progressive tense, which is used in describing this moment. Present perfect progressive tense is the best to use here to describe the increasing situation over years.